# Transforming a String into a number an reverting it PHP

Tags: php, math, string

I need to check if  a number is palindrome, i started thinking maybe the best way to do it, is transforming the number into a string and verifying the reverse string is the same.

The problem is that when i use the following code i got the wrong result.

```
<?PHP 

function palindrome($number){
      $value = strval($number);
      $reverse_value = strrev($value);

      if($value == strrev($value)){
         echo " $number is a palindrome";
         echo  gettype($value);
         }else{
          echo "$number is not a palindrome";
          echo $value." ".strrev($value);
         }
}

$number = 90209;


palindrome($number);
?>
```

Can somebody explain me the diference?

Comment: What result do you get?  When I run this, I get: " 90209 is a palindrome"

Comment: What result are you getting? I seem to be getting correct results with your code. `90209 is a palindrome` and `90219 is not a palindrome`

Comment: Seems to work for me. I get "90209 is a palindromestring".

Comment: if I run this code with PHP 5.3.3 it tells me that `palindrome(90209)` is true

Comment: The problem is, this item is not a palindrome,A palindromic number reads the same both ways. Straight and reverse, that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have deeper problems, because I just put that code into an ide:

https://ideone.com/yJEz1

Result: `90209 is a palindromestring`

And it successfully put out the value.  You may want to check your php.ini with regard to changed mathematical settings, or just run the code again in a different context, or clean up duplication in the code, and it may give you the right result.

Here is the same code using `(string)` casting to ensure the string type (I've never used the strval() function, personally, I just force cast a type).  It works in all of three test cases.
https://ideone.com/4bI0O

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, although you're not actually using $reverse_value at all.

```
if ($value == $reverse_value)
{
     ...
```

What does your system say $value and $reverse_value actually are?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an optimized version that works:

```
function is_palindrome( $value ) {
    $reverse_value = strrev( $value );

    if ( $value == $reverse_value ) {
        echo print_r( $value, true ) . "is a palindrome. The reverse is: " . print_r( $reverse_value, true ) . "<br />";
    }
    else {
        echo print_r( $value, true ) . "is a not a palindrome. The reverse is: " . print_r( $reverse_value, true ) . "<br />";
    }
}
```

There is no need to convert the value to a string; this happens automatically. Also, your code called strrev() twice, so I removed the redundant one.